# How to identify prior for the precision parameter in Winbugs

Tags: bugs

I have the following model:

```
model{
     for (i in 1:n){
        y[i] ~dnorm(mu[i], tau)
        mu[i] <- a + b*x[i]
      } 
      
      a ~ dnorm(0, 1.0E-6)
      b ~ dnorm(0, 1.0E-6)
   
      tau ~ dnorm(0,1.0E-6)

      sigma <- 1/sqrt(tau)
 }
```

In `tau ~ dnorm(0,1.0E-6)` ( prior for the precision parameter), what are the numbers inside the parentheses `(0,1.0E-6)`? Where did they come from?

Answer (score 0):

WinBUGS uses “precision” as a parameter in specifying a Normal distribution, instead of variance.

Precision = $\frac{1}{\text{Variance}}$

`dnorm(0, 0.0001)` is the same as a Normal distribution with mean
0 and variance $\frac{1}{0.0001} = 100^2$, or $\sim \mathcal{N}(0,100^2)$

## Edit

In response to the question, I assume your model looks something like this...

```
model { 
   for (i in 1:n) { 
      y[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i], tau) 
      mu[i] <- a + b*x[i]
   }

   a ~ dnorm(0, 1.0E-6)
   b ~ dnorm(0, 1.0E-6)

   tau ~ dnorm(0,1.0E-6)

   sigma <- 1/sqrt(tau)
}
```

So, you simulate a $\tau$ value as $\sim \mathcal{N}(0, \frac{1}{1.0E-6})$, then use that $\tau$ value to calculate $y[i]$, such that $$y[i] \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0, \frac{1}{\mathcal{N}(0, \frac{1}{1.0E-6})}\right).$$

Using a mean-zero Gaussian is standard practice for most people simulating random positive-or-negative errors.  I do not know why you chose $1.0 \times 10^{-6}$ as your precision parameter. It is your model, not mine.

Comment: Thank you E. Trauger- What is the basis of  the mean and  variance selected as prior knowledge in the this regression model

Comment: Thanks- I did not chose it, but I am still not clear how I can chose  a tau value as prior knowledge. Any help?

Comment: What is "$\mathcal{N}(0, \frac{1}{\mathcal{N}(0, \frac{1}{1.0E-6})})$" intended to mean when the denominator of the second parameter (which apparently is meant to be a variance) turns out *negative*, which it has a $50\%$ chance of doing?